# What's the opposite of "cost" when downgrading and you get some of the money back?

Tags: antonyms

For example, I'm playing a game where it costs $5 to upgrade one of my weapons.
Thus I have an "upgrade cost" of $5.

When I want to downgrade my weapon and I only get $3 back for it, what would be the opposite word for cost?

- Upgrade cost of $5
- Downgrade `X` of $3

Comment: how about "reward"?

Comment: @A.Ellett I think reward is something you get for successing at something, this is basically about selling something back to someone.

Comment: Maybe it's a *trade-in allowance*

Comment: Or, using verbs, upgrade costs $5, downgrade pays $3.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a **refund**.

Comment: **Refund** seems like the word I was looking for! Thank you very much, I'll accept as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 14):

I'd say "rebate". It is defined so:

- n. A partial refund to someone who has paid too much for tax, rent, or a utility. *The scheme eases the move to the council tax by giving rebates in the first year*.
- v [with obj.] Pay back (a sum of money) as a rebate. *The government rebates part of your own and your employer's National Insurance contributions into the plan*.

Comment: Rebate is too entangled with the semantics and context of the action, the base of the whole thing is a refund. It's nice to have a good, concrete synonym though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I personally wouldn't have had any idea what the difference between **refund** and **rebate** is, but @Sakatox seems to have known. Thanks to both of you :)

Comment: +1 for a good word that includes the notion that not all the cost is being recaptured.

Comment: Rebate means something completely different from what OP asked for. It's not money returned as part of returning/exchanging the item bought but a (often deceptive) form of discount/price-adjustment on purchases.

Comment: @R.. It’s not my answer to defend, but in spite of the problems it might have, “[rebate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rebate)” does have the notion of “partial” already built into it and doesn’t require prefacing with “partial” to fully capture the “less-than-full” scenario presented in the OP’s example, unlike many of the other answers given so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you described and named the second, downgrading transaction more in terms of it being a return of the original upgrade (instead of giving it the separate name of “downgrade”), you could perhaps call it an upgrade “[return allowance](https://books.google.com/books?id=2hOx9HrH2UcC&pg=PA117&dq=%22return+allowance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiesP7h7anLAhXCFh4KHUUBBYMQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22return%20allowance%22&f=false) (upgrade cost less fixed restocking fee/depreciation).
(example usage from ‘Wiley GAAP Policies and Procedures’ by Steven M. Bragg, via ‘Google Books’)

For a single word that you could use with “downgrade” that implies that some, but not all of the upgrade cost is being returned, there’s “downgrade [offset](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offset)," which ‘Merriam-Webster’ defines as:
6 :  something that serves to counterbalance or to compensate for something else; especially :  either of two balancing ledger items

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *reimbursement*:

The definition of *reimburse* is

1. To make repayment for expense or loss occurred,
2. To pay back; refund; repay

According to dictionary.com

Comment: The form of the word to answer the question is *reimbursement*

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of *costs* is **pays**. A winning lottery ticket pays $10. Downgrade payment of $3.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use "saving". It fits the situation better where one is merely considering the options. A "refund" is what you get back *after* you've made a payment.

Answer (score -1):

In the context of video games, I would suggest simply **sell or sale price**.

I would not use "refund" for this situation. What you are doing, in the fiction of the video game world, is selling the item to a vendor, and the vendor will probably resell it for a profit. This has much more in common with selling or pawning a good; the item has *less value* than what you paid due to usage or the costs involved in reselling it. You're not just taking the original good back to where you bought it; you are participating in a market where goods are exchanged. "Refund" does not properly connote this.